# Jmeter giving error code 401 for few requests while running in a loop

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I've used dynamic authentication to generate the token , my test plan is like login - request1 , request2, request 3. When running it for a single time it gives no error , but when I'm running this script for 5 minutes , I'm getting few errors in between as 401 for few requests. I've tried putting in login in logic controller , yet I'm not able to get rid of the error , the error only comes when I run it over a loop

Comment: It seems you reach your limit on server, you can add delays if needed

Comment: But it's showing error even for 10 users with script running time of 1 minute

Comment: some server/firewall limit number of users per seconds/period

Comment: Anything else that could cause the error ?

Comment: have you used cookie and cache managers in Test Plan?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try with few things:
1. Header manager to pass the dynamic token.
2. Use a Debug Sampler in loop
3. Add a delay in loop.

If not then please elaborate the questions !

Comment: I've added a header manager to pass the dynamic token. The test plan runs fine when exected for once , but when I run it in loop in non gui mode on command line setting the thread lifetime as 300 seconds , I get error like 401 in the dashboard report

Comment: your token gets invalidated for the next request probably. Make sure to pass the dynamic token for each request ..try putting the header manager inside the loop which will carry your dynamic token value as ${token} for each subsequent requests